# How to read @array from android:tag?

Tags: android, arrays, string, reference, tags

I have a reference to a string array inside the tag attribute. How can I read it in order to get hands on the array?

My layout with the tag attribute:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/btn" ... android:tag="@array/colors" />
```

My arrays.xml:

```
<string-array name="colors">
    <item>red</item>
    <item>yellow</item>
    <item>green</item>
</string-array>
```

This way I fetch the tag (unfortunately as Object):

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
Object tag = btn.getTag();
Log.d("COLORS", "tag: " + tag.toString());
```

The log output is:

```
03-06 13:34:12.765: DEBUG/COLORS(2957): tag: @2131099648
```

As I take a closer look in my R.java:

```
public static final int colors=0x7f060000;
```

This hexadecimal value is exactly:

```
2131099648
```

So somehow there must be a way the get this Object and get the ressource identifier as an int.

Instead of

```
String[] colors = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colors);
```

I want to do something like this:

```
String[] colors = getResources().getStringArray((int)tag);
```

Thank you for helping me on this,

Marco

Comment: Are u not getting the array using String[] colors = getResources().getStringArray((int)tag);

Comment: Unfortunately String[] colors = getResources().getStringArray((Integer) tag); produces a java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String

Comment: Then go even uglier and use Integer.parseInt((String)tag) ?  :) though I guess you'd have to ignore the first character in the string before parsing etc... there must be a better way

Comment: Well, I found this (rather unholy) solution: `String strTag = (String) tag; String[] colors = getResources().getStringArray(Integer.parseInt(strTag.substring(1)));`

I take the tag, cast it into String, so I get "@2131099648", then I throw away the "@", cast it into Integer, use this Integer as ressource identifier...

Comment: The @ prefix is the result of a `TypedValue#coerceToString(..)` when the View was inflated - unfortunately the `Resources#getIdentifier(String name, .., ..)` has an `Integer.parseInt(..)` as the first test before returning the id from the asset manager - but it totally misses that Android itself prefixes resource identifiers with '@' in `TypedValue` :-P

Comment: If you got the solution please write in answer for others

Answer (score 1):

Use `colors.xml` inside `res/values` folder and then you can use:

```
<resources>
    <color name="solid_red">#f00</color>
    <color name="solid_blue">#0000ff</color>
    <color name="solid_green">#f0f0</color>
    <color name="solid_yellow">#ffffff00</color>
</resources>
```

Then you can use something like this:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/btn" ... android:tag="@color/solid_red" />
```

Comment: maybe color was a bad example. let's say it's all about planets... In my tag I want to reference the whole array, but in Java the getTag() method only returns Object. So actually I am searching for a convenience method to get the ressoource identifier...

Comment: you can use like     String[] myImageFileEndings = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fileEndingImage) in code.